# URL for Google Plus and Twitter -share doesn't change after ajax load

Tags: ajax, wordpress, twitter

I have a WordPress website using Advanced Ajax Page Loader. On various pages I have a URL share function for Facebook, LinkedIn, Twitter & Google Plus. When clicked the Facebook & LinkedIn button share the current URL - The Twitter & Google Plus buttons only share the URL of the main website (root), unless the page is refreshed.

The code i'm currently using is the following.

In header:

```
     <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id))
                return;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=390609237745022&version=v2.0";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <script>!function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }
        }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
    <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">lang: nl_NL</script>
```

Called (on the pages):

```
<div class="social-icons">
                        <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></div>
                        <!--<div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php //the_permalink();          ?>" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>-->
                        <div class="in">
                            <script type="IN/Share" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></script>
                        </div>
                        <div class="google">
                            <g:plusone></g:plusone>
                        </div>
                        <div class="twitter">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I use custom icons for my share buttons.

I've been pretty much looking for a solution for 2 weeks now; any help would be more than welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved the Tweet button by using:**

In the header

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">lang: nl_NL</script>
```

In the body

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="nl"></a>
```

Basically the data URL attribute was added to the body.

**Google plus was a little trickier, but was solved as follows:**

In the header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js" async defer></script>

<script>{"parsetags": "explicit"} function renderWidget() { gapi.plusone.render("google" ); } </script>
```

In the body

```
<div class="google">
  <g:plusone href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></g:plusone>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Plus share button parameters in this document: https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/
I see **data-href** attr, this can be your need.
And Twitter sharebutton parameters in this document: https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/parameters Twitter has **data-url** and **data-count-url**

Comment: The twitter tip worked. Adding data-url fixed the problem. The google issue is not yet resolved however. I added the data-href to <g:plusone></...>, but to no avail.

Comment: Use this code fully for G+ : `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script><div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-href="http://your_domainname"></div>`

Comment: If I use the <div class="g-plus"...> code the button won't render on first load / it's just not there. I don't have that problem with <g:plusone></g:plusone>. So that would actually be an extra set back.